# How can I rename value from one column?

Tags: r

The value is there 500 times and the name of the value is composed of many different characters.

Data.frame like this:

```
head(df)
# Job                                                               Opinion
# Superskilled worker/skilled worker - who has at least 5 workers   No
# Manager                                                           Yes                                                          
# Officer                                                           No                                                            
# Superskilled worker/skilled worker - who has at least 5 workers   Yes
# Superskilled worker/skilled worker - who has at least 5 workers   Yes
# Manager                                                           Yes
# Officer                                                           Yes
# Manager                                                           No
# Superskilled worker/skilled worker - who has at least 5 workers   No
```

I want to rename "Superskilled worker/skilled worker - who has at least 5 workers" to "Skilled worker".

Comment: I want to rename "Superskilled worker/skilled worker - who has at least 5 workers" to "Skilled worker".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

option 1

```
df$Job <- sub("Superskilled worker///skilled worker - who has at least 5 workers","Skilled worker",df$Job)
```

option 2

```
df$Job[df$Job=="Superskilled worker/skilled worker - who has at least 5 workers"] <- "Skilled worker"
```

Comment: It works only for renaming values without special characters. If there is /, or -, or number. It doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sub()`.

```
df$Job <- sub(".*(skilled worker).*", "\\1", df$Job)
```